# Cordova android adaptive icons v26?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

does anyone know why my android build has additional v26 icons?

I've specified the below resources in my config.xml but the android build also adds additional v26 folders mipmap-ldpi-v26, mipmap-hdpi-v26 etc that have no asset.

I read quite a bit and can't see anyone else with this issue.

```
cordova-android": "11.0.0"    

<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="33" />

<resource-file src="resources-android/values/ic_launcher_background.xml" target="app/src/main/res/values/ic_launcher_background.xml" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
<resource-file src="resources-android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

icon_backgroud.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background">#4e99c6</color>
    <color name="cdv_splashscreen_background">#4e99c6</color>
</resources>
```

drop ldpi, android will use mdpi now,

```
<resource-file src="resources/icon-background.xml" target="/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml" />
<icon background="@color/background" density="mdpi" foreground="resources/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" src="resources/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
<icon background="@color/background" density="hdpi" foreground="resources/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" src="resources/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
<icon background="@color/background" density="xhdpi" foreground="resources/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" src="resources/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
<icon background="@color/background" density="xxhdpi" foreground="resources/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" src="resources/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
<icon background="@color/background" density="xxxhdpi" foreground="resources/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" src="resources/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).